# Compatible WiFi extender/WAP for University captive network

Tags: wifi

So I’m a Uni student living on campus at WSU Australia, and they have a login system for the WiFi which it asks me for 2 things, my Identification (student number) and password (student password) - This rules me out from using so many devices. I have got work arounds for most of these, but it’s annoying - in general by default I cannot connect the following -

My smart watch (Gear S3 Frontier) (not too big of an issue as it's usually just paired with my phone)

My PlayStation 4/Xbox

My Google home Mini

My printer (Wouldn't connect it on an open network anyway)

My Dyson Pure Cool tower

and some other devices here and there, but not as important.

My current work around is setting up my Windows Surface laptop as a portable hotspot, but this has several setbacks, such as -

I am constantly removing my laptop from my room, whenever I do these devices lose connection,

The laptop doesn't carry over much of the Uni Wifi’s exceptional speed and can't handle many devices

SO MUCH LAG WHEN IM ONLINE GAMING WITH MY PS4

So what I'm looking for is recommendations for a WiFi Extender/WAP, (Netgear preferred) that can connect to the Uni's portal asking for student login and password. There is an ethernet port in my room, but the student accommodation has decided to pull the plug on those so you can't access any form of connection if you plug something in. So it would have to be able to connect to the captive login and only on a wireless connection. I obviously do not have the option to link the Uni WAP with my own extender, but I do have access to the WAP in the common room of my apt.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you post your price limit. Given your constraints and general annoyances of University network systems, you may require something more than a simple AP point or otherwise. Have you tried contacting your University IT services for advice?

Comment: I'm annoyed at all of this so I don't really have a price limit, ill save for it. And yes, and obviously they don't have anything to say because they don't recommend it.

Comment: Perhaps, you might be interested in buying a cheap dedicated computer with a decent (preferably ac network adapter) and using this [software](https://www.connectify.me/) or the hotspot software you already have. I have used this to turn my laptop into a router by plugging into an Ethernet at schools that didn't give us the wifi password during competitions to share with my classmates (this was back in high school).